# How to measure percentage greater than an aggregation in tableau

Tags: count, conditional-statements, tableau-api

Let's consider this :

```
Student | Score

S1          87

S2          75

S3          52
```

I want to create a pie chart or horizontal chart showing what percentage of students scored more than the average score.

According to the above example, 
Avg(Score) = 71.33

% of students scoring more than avg(score) is 66.67%   (S1 & S2)

Already gone through [How to count occurrence of value and percentage of a subset in tableau public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33714710/how-to-count-occurrence-of-value-and-percentage-of-a-subset-in-tableau-public) but in that question, the comparison is against a static value rather than an aggregated value.

Comment: Learn about Level of Detail (LOD) calculations.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using a **window calculation**.

Create a calculated field called 'Above Average' with the calculation

```
IF AVG([Score]) > WINDOW_AVG(AVG([Score])) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Now you can filter out your dataset to only use values where 'Above Average' > 0 and create your pie chart.